# How to make slide animation for titanium

Tags: titanium

I have one window and one view and this view cover the 76% of the screen.

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    navBarHidden: true,
});

var view = Ti.UI.createView({
    backgroundColor:backgroundColor , 
    width:'76%',right:0,left:'24%',
    height:'100%'
});

win.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    win.add(view);
});
```

What I want to do is sliding the view from right slide of the screen.
How do I do this?
I guess I should use animate method though ,,,,
Does anyone have sample source or something??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To animate something, you will indeed need to use the `animate` method.
Here is an example for you:

```
var view = Ti.UI.createView({
    backgroundColor:'yellow',
    width:'76%',
    right:-Ti.Platform.displayCaps.getPlatformWidth(),
    onScreen:false
});
win.tiview.add(view);

win.tiview.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    var viewShowAnimation = Ti.UI.createAnimation({
       duration:250,
       right:0
    });
    var viewHideAnimation = Ti.UI.createAnimation({
       duration:250,
       right:-Ti.Platform.displayCaps.getPlatformWidth()
    });
    if(view.onScreen){
       view.animate(viewShowAnimation);
    }else{
       view.animate(viewHideAnimation);
    }
    view.onScreen = !view.onScreen;
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!. it helps me.  Maybe in sample code `if(view.onScreen){` should be `if(!view.onScreen){` .